# How to set a foreign key using Entity Framework fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have 2 entities TblCountry and TblState where I want to set a foreign key for one to many relationship. Forign key CountryId from TblState will refer to TblCountry> CountryId.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:DefaultSchema", "dbo");
    modelBuilder.Entity<TblCountry>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.CountryId);

        entity.ToTable("tbl_Countries", "dbo");

        entity.Property(e => e.CountryId).HasColumnName("CountryId");
        entity.Property(e => e.CountryName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(120)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasMaxLength(1).HasDefaultValue(1);
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<TblState>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.StateId);

        entity.ToTable("tbl_States", "dbo");

        entity.Property(e => e.StateId).HasColumnName("StateID");

        entity.Property(e => e.StateName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(120)
            .IsUnicode(false);
        entity.Property(e => e.CountryId)
        entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasMaxLength(1).HasDefaultValue(1);
    });
}
```

I have tried below way but not working for me.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<TblState>().HasOne<TblCountry>
 (s => s.CountryId).WithMany(g => g.CountryId).HasForeignKey(s => s.CountryId);
```

Getting error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type...

Comment: Just look at the [extensive documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key).

Comment: Thanks for the link @GertArnold..